# grafana use ldap on windows grafana server

Tags: windows, ldap, grafana

Disclaimer 1: New to grafana but not new to ldap usage with other tools but only with Linux installs.

Disclaimer 2: My question applies to a Windows install of grafana

There is a ldap toml file in the conf folder on windows but the config file is `/etc/grafana/ldap.toml`

So how to a `reference/connect` A windows grafana install to utilize ldap and employ a `ldap.toml` file in `C:\Program Files\grafana-5.2.4\conf`

i.e. change the following from

```
grafana.ini:config_file = /etc/grafana/ldap.toml
```

to

```
grafana.ini:config_file = C:\Program Files\grafana-5.2.4\conf \ldap.toml
```

Answer (score 2):

uncomment the line and change it to:

grafana.ini:config_file = C:\Program Files\grafana-5.2.4\conf \ldap.toml

It expects an escape character in windows installation.